# Calendar Pop-Up not working in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, calendar

I got this pop-up calendar from the internet and I can run it using `IE`. But when I tried to browse it using `Firefox` or `Chrome`, the pop-up calendar is not working.

This is the external js file place in the `<head>` [DL calendar.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77904260/calendar.js):

```
<script src="../script/calendar.js?d6aa97d33d459ea3670056e737c99a3d" 
     type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Code in HTML:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="blackcopy" name="txtReadyDate" id="txtReadyDate" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
<input type="button" name="btnStartShipDate" style="width: 30px; height: 19px" value="..."/>
```

And I have this javascript code which trigger the click event in the button. It is place at the last part with the rest of the codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sDetector;
    var sStop;

    calendar.set("btnStartShipDate", "txtReadyDate", "left", 130, -20, document.frmObject.txtReadyDate.value);

    function onMouseMove(val) {
        if (sStop == 'stop') {
            return false;
        }
        sDetector = val;
    }

    function sHide() {
        if (sStop == 'stop') {
            sStop = "";
            calendar.hideCalendar()
        }

        if (sDetector == 'hide') {
            calendar.hideCalendar()
            sDetector = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

The calendar looks like this when it is working:

[image]

Any code there which has conflicts or not compatible with `Firefox` & `Chrome`?

Comment: does the script not need to be in document.load?

Comment: what is the content of `calendar.js` ? Highly recommend you use jQuery UI's date picker

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I editted my post and includes download link for calendar.js

Comment: @user2310289: I havn't tried that. But it is working in IE without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what is worng. Some where in the code of `calendar.js` you will see a code like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById(input_id);
```

which is actually refering to this input:

```
<input type="button" name="btnStartShipDate" style="width: 30px; height: 19px" value="..."/>
```

Since `getElementById` refer to an `id` you need to put it an `id` attribute like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnStartShipDate" name="btnStartShipDate" style="width: 30px; height: 19px" value="..."/>
```

---

The thing is, `IE browse` can somehow work it out even if the `input` only has a `name` attribute. But for the case of `Firefox` and `Chrome`, `getElementById` does not work until there is an `id` attribute in the control.

Comment: Helps a lot save my ass